# Removing an iOS contact group

Tags: ios, cncontactstore

Anyone tried to remove an existing contact group using the iOS 9 Contacts framework?

I initialize the contact store and request the list of contact groups, which gives me an array of `CNGroup` instances:

```
var groups: [CNGroup]?

do {
    self.groups = try contactStore.groupsMatchingPredicate(nil)
}
catch { ... }
```

and then I show the groups in a table view. When the user swipes a table view cell, I would like to delete the corresponding group from the contact store.

However, the `deleteGroup` method of `CNContactStore` requires a `CNMutableGroup` instance, not a `CNGroup`. Xcode gives me an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'CNGroup' to expected type 'CNMutableGroup'
```

Obviously, if I try to cast the `CNGroup` instance to a `CNMutableGroup`:

```
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
saveRequest.deleteGroup(group as! CNMutableGroup)
do {
    try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
}
catch { ... }
```

I get a crash at runtime:

```
Could not cast value of type 'CNGroup' (0x370890f8) to 'CNMutableGroup' (0x370899f4)
```

I realize that this is because `CNGroup` is a superclass of `CNMutableGroup`, but then again I can't see how to get a `CNMutableGroup` initialized with a `CNGroup` instance.

I have requested access to the Contacts framework. Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.2.1.

So, any ideas on how to delete a contact group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting a mutable copy of the CNGroup fixes this.

```
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
saveRequest.deleteGroup(group.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableGroup)
do {
    try contactStore.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
}
catch { ... }
```

Comment: Finally verified this in iOS 10.3 with Xcode 8.3 + Swift 3.1, as "try contactStore.execute(saveRequest)" in the latest API syntax. Thanks!